# Can I check SkSL bundle engine version with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, skia, application-warmup

I have recorded SkSl script to warmup shaders. I use this build option to apply it for my Flutter app's release builds:

```
flutter build appbundle --release --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json
```

It works great, but it stops work when new Flutter version released. In that case I have an error:

```
Expected Flutter b8752bbfff0419c8bf616b602bc59fd28f6a3d1b, but found 2c956a31c0a3d350827aee6c56bb63337c5b4e6e
The SkSL bundle was produced with a different engine version. It must be recreated for the current Flutter version.
```

I want to detect this error without building my release app (as a merge check on CI).

**The question:** is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, Any update ??

Comment: @NhậtTrần Hi! I didn't find a way to check engine version used to generate specific sksl script. I just stop to use newest flutter version (remove `flutter upgrade` from CI script) and use `git checkout ${FLUTTER_VERSION} && flutter precache` to get flutter version specified in environment variables. This way I can control flutter versions on CI. Github issue about using specific flutter version - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64238

Comment: I fixed it that problem. Open terminal and flutter run. After that press M  to write the captured SkSL. the file flutter_01.sksl.json will be generated. Thank you so much!